# Create MLM type tree structure with javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, recursion, iteration

I want to create MLM type tree structure. I have array **ARR** with all its childs, and again **ARR** array contain all sub arrays present in it.

**Example:**

```
ARR['MainArr'] = aray('child1'=>'child1 val', 'child2'=>'child2 val');

ARR['child1'] = array('subchild1'=>'subchild1 val');

ARR['child2'] = array('...'=>'...');

ARR['subchild1'] = array('...'=>'...');
```

and so on...

I want to loop all these arrays recursively without using any function(if possible) to get and print all its sub childs till printing all childs.

In the following example `parsedAllSpurs` array contains all the sub childs just like `ARR` array here.

```
tmpHN = spurs.hostname;
while(typeof(parsedAllSpurs[tmpHN]) !== 'undefined'){
    if(typeof(parsedAllSpurs[tmpHN]) !== 'undefined'){
        $.each(parsedAllSpurs[tmpHN], function(k, allSpurs){
            tmpHN1 = allSpurs.hostname;
            log(tmpHN1);
            log(allSpurs);

            while(typeof(parsedAllSpurs[tmpHN1]) !== 'undefined'){
                if(typeof(parsedAllSpurs[tmpHN1]) !== 'undefined'){
                    $.each(parsedAllSpurs[tmpHN1], function(j, allSpurs1){
                        tmpHN2 = allSpurs1.hostname; 
                        //log(tmpHN2);
                        log(allSpurs1);

                        while(typeof(parsedAllSpurs[tmpHN2]) !== 'undefined'){
                            if(typeof(parsedAllSpurs[tmpHN2]) !== 'undefined'){
                                $.each(parsedAllSpurs[tmpHN2], function(l, allSpurs2){
                                    tmpHN2 = allSpurs2.hostname;     
                                    log(allSpurs2);

                                })

                            }
                        }

                        tmpHN1 = allSpurs1.hostname;
                    });                                                
                }
            }

            tmpHN = allSpurs.hostname;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is your code inside a function?

Comment: I don't really get the structure of your  `parsedAllSpurs` JavaScript object. Can you please include an example of that in your code? Like `var parsedAllSpurs = <something here>`. And where does `spurs.hostname` come from? What is the `spurs` variable?

Comment: Following is the structure of parsedAllSuprs, But its PHP array, later on converted into json object          `array
(
    'MIBHRAWLESR001' => array
    (
        0 => array
        (
            'hostname' => 'MIBHVENKESR001'
            'media_type' => 'Microwave'
        )
        1 => array
        (
            'hostname' => 'ABCDEF000'
            'media_type' => 'Microwave'
        )
        2 => array
        (
            'hostname' => 'MIBHSLSRESR001'
            'media_type' => 'Microwave'
        )
    )
)`

Comment: My code is not in function @aldrin27

Comment: I cannot see the connection between any elements in that array. Could you provide a more complete example on the array (please include it in your question, not as a comment)? If you want a JavaScript  solution I guess it would be better to write the example as a JavaScript object. Or do you want a PHP solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion instead on nested loops https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion.
Create function that do it for one level, and call this function each time you found nested structure.

```
function processStructure(data){
    processData(data);
    if(hasChildren(data)){
        processStructure(data);
    }
}
processStructure(initialData);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can't we do this without using function, like we can use while or foreach

Comment: Every each in your example creates anonymous function, what is the problem with one function? Your code contains copy-paste, what if you will have one more level? You will copy it again? And what if after you will need to add data processing? You will write it to every function ?